# need a formula for setting indexes of an arraylist using 2 for loops

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to use 2 for loops to set each value of each element in the arraylist to zero. Problem is that I need a formula to set each index to be 0 through 9. This formula would be placed where it says "FORMULA" in the below code. My desired result would be a printed line of {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,} using the exact same code as below but with "FORMULA" being replaced with an appropriate formula to set the correct index through each loop. Let me know if you need further a explanation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListPractice {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[]){
         setArrayValues();
         System.out.println(x);
     }

    private static void setArrayValues() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            x.add(i);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<5; j++){
                x.set(FORMULA, 0);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you start with the list of all pairs of values that i and j take and write them down.

Comment: It seems like a question you would get in programming class. If it is, take a look at the comment before this and try to figure it out yourself. After all, you're there to try to learn things.

Comment: been doing that in excel for over an hour, still no luck :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried writing down all the values that `i` and `j` can take?

Comment: yes I have been doing this in excel for over an hour, trying to figure out a formula

Comment: You sure it shouldn't be: `for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            for(int j=i; j<5; j++){
                x.set(FORMULA, 0);
            }
        }`
 ? It'd be hard to get 15 values otherwise.

Comment: apologies, should be 10 values instead. I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then the next will work:

`FORMULA = 10 - ((4-i)*(5-i))/2 + (4-j)`

**Explanation:**

you want if i=0: FORMULA = 0+(4-j)
you want if i=1: FORMULA = 4+(4-j)
you want if i=2: FORMULA = 7+(4-j)
you want if i=3: FORMULA = 9+(4-j)

your outer loop goes from 0 to 4, so:

`FORMULA = (sum {k=0 to 4} k) - (sum {k=0 to 4-i} k) + (4-j)`

This is equal to:

`1/2 4 (1+4)-1/2 (4-i) (1+(4-i)) + (4-j)`

Which in turn is equal to:

`10 - ((4-i)*(5-i))/2 + (4-j)`

Note how I multiply before dividing. This way I can use integer division without loosing data, because either `4-i` or `5-i` is even, therefore `(4-i)*(5-i)` is even.

If you even want all the numbers to be in order, replace every occurrence of `(4-j)` with `(j-(i+1))` or `(j-i-1)`. Then you'd get index 0-9 in order.

Comment: I'm getting an out of bounds exception when I use that formula. Also a quick substitution of i=0 and j=1 yields 3 when it should be zero.

Comment: @anonymousnoob [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10+-+%28%284-j%29*%285-j%29%29%2F2+%2B+%284-k%29+for+j+%3D+[0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3]+and+k+%3D+[1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+3%2C+4%2C+4]) you can see that the formula generates all indexes from 0 to 9. I think that the indexes were out of bounds because I edited my explanation (It had a few errors previously)

Comment: Ah yes it works out now. Thank you my good sir. Is there by any chance a way to make the result be ordered like {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} rather than {3,2,1,0,6,5,4,8,7,9}?

Comment: That depends on the (4-j) term. If you replace it with (j-i-1), then I think it is in the right order.

Comment: you should be canonized because you're one hell of a saint

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set 10 (or A * B) elements, you will have to apply the formula A * B times. If C and D are the limits to your inner and outer loop, the formula will be applied C * D times, in your current code 5 * 5 = 25 times (not 5 + 5 = 10!), so you’ve got some overkill there. So choose C and D more appropriately.

Then it’s a good idea choose a way to divide the elements of `x` into C groups of D elements, each group to be filled with one complete execution of the inner loop – there’s a very obvious choice for that. Having got that far, you should know what value your formula should take for each pair, and I feel you should be able to find it from that: I presume this is an exercise from which you are meant to learn.

Comment: actually, when i=0, then j iterates over 1,2,3,4(4 times). When i=1, then j iterates over 2,3,4(3 times). When i=2, then j iterates over 3,4(2 times). When i=3, then j iterates over 4(1 time). When i=4, then j iterates zero times. So the formula will be applied 4+3+2+1=10 times. Keep in mind that the initial value in my second for loop is j=i+1 not j=i which would iterate 25 times.

Comment: So you are indeed getting the triangular number `n(n-1)/2` of applications, i.e. 10 in this case. Was that specified as part of the problem? In that case you start each new inner loop with the number of positions filled being the sum of the first `i` terms of 4,3,2,1 – but thinking about the unfilled positions suggests a simpler formula.

Comment: I'm trying to implement collision detection as part of a larger program. I ran into a problem like this and just simplified the problem for everyone's convenience.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought this must be a somewhat artificial exercise, which is why I was reluctant to provide the answer. Since that is apparently not the case, could you please explain why it is not an option to initialise the entire array in one loop: what are the constraints on the solution you want? In particular, are your inner and outer loop required to set up the elements in the order of their indices? I suppose you are also not inserting 0, but something more complicated.

Comment: My outer loop has if statements that need to iterate by as many bouncing balls as I place into the program. These if statements dictate collision detection between each ball and a wall. The inner loop has if statements that in conjunction with the outer loop needs to iterate by as many relationships there are between balls. These if statements dictate collision detection between the balls themselves. However, I realized I can probably split up the 2 loops which would end my reliance on this long formula. With a separate loop, I'd have to iterate 0.5*b^2-0.5*b times, where b is the # of balls.

Comment: On second thought, I'll still need to do it through 2 nested loops since the 0.5*b^2-0.5*b loop is dependent on arrays with b elements. Sorry if my explanations are bad but dat comment limit tho.